# Maven release plugin throws error when connecting to TFS repo using HTTPS - maven doesnt trust cert

Tags: maven, tfs

I have a HTTPS enabled TFS repo which I am trying to connect to via maven release plugin - when i run release:prepare, it throws error saying could not find root ca for the certificate TFS is presenting. Is there any option in maven to suggest something like "trustcacerts" - i know it exists for SVN - would it work for TFS as well? Any way out will be nice..

Answer (score 0):

Try retrieving the SSL certificate first.
http://kingsfleet.blogspot.ca/2007/07/q-how-do-i-get-remote-server-ssl-cert.html?m=1

Then follow the instructions from one of my previous answers here:
[SSL client certificate in Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17025703/ssl-client-certificate-in-maven/17028647#17028647)