# How to configure maven wagon plugin to allow insecure ssl?

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, maven-wagon-plugin

At our company we have `artifactory` running on an https server.

I could access the artifacts by adding the cert of the server to the java keystore.

But i would rather set the properties:

```
maven.wagon.http.ssl.insecure = true  
maven.wagon.http.ssl.allowall = true
```

My question is: where can is set these? Ideally it would be in the pom

Comment: If you correctly can add the cert and it's working why would  you like to ignore the cert and make your connection less secure?

Comment: On my machine i dont have access to the keystore, hence i cannot add the key.

Comment: Sorry? If you are in the company you should have access to them to make the transfer more secure

Comment: I think i found what i was looking for: [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17025703/ssl-client-certificate-in-maven)

Comment: Ok ignore existing security..It's your turn..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to tell Maven to disregard SSL errors (and trusting all certs)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21252800/how-to-tell-maven-to-disregard-ssl-errors-and-trusting-all-certs)